# React Router v4.0.0 + react bootstrap

Tags: react-router

I'm using React Router v4 with react-bootstrap. The problem is that the routing doesn't work when I try to click on "FrontPage" or "About" page when it is styled with react-bootstrap. If I take off the react-boostrap, the routing works fine. How can I fix it so that this works with react-boostrap?

> ```
>  <ul>
>       <li><Link to='/'>Home</Link></li>
>       <li><Link to='/about'>About</Link></li>
>       <li><Link to='/frontPage'>frontPage</Link></li>
>     </ul>
>     <hr/>
>       <Route exactly path='/' component={Home}/>
>       <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
>       <Route path='/frontPage' component={FrontPage}/>
> ```

the above code will work however, the below code will not.

```
          <Nav>
            <NavItem><Link to='/frontpage' > Adventure</Link></NavItem>
            <NavItem><Link to='/about' > About</Link></NavItem>
              <hr/>
                <Router exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                <Router path='/frontpage' component={FrontPage}/>
                <Router path='/about' component={About}/> 
           </Nav>
```

Error I get in console:

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
    at C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\server.js:24:23
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
    at param (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
    at next (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\send\index.js:282:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\send\index.js:433:12)
    at onstat (C:\Users\louis\desktop\testreact\node_modules\send\index.js:734:26)
```

To clarify the issue: If I do not style with react-boostrap, the routing will work as intended by switching to the desired routes when I click on frontpage and about page. However, once I wrap the routes with bootstrap tags, I cannot switch from one page to another. It returns as "Path is not defined".

Comment: What "does not work"

Comment: @WilomGfx I edited my post to clarify the issue.

Comment: Do you get an errors in the console ?

Comment: Yes, I added that to the post just now

Comment: Without a way of replicating the error ex: jsbin or a codepen. I cant really do much. But id look at the code generated by react-bootstrap for that component : https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/NavItem.js

Comment: In the example with `Nav`s you have `Router` instead of `Route`

Comment: @jakee Wow.. Jake thank you so much. I spent days trying to wrap my head around what went wrong in my code and all because of the "Router" and "Route". You pointed out the error in the code, thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

dude you put Router not Route, unless that was intentional
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route
Router does not accept path